# Http Post Request android in a different thread

Tags: android, http-post

I am new to android and I am trying to make an http post request and I am getting the following error, I have posted my code and some lines of my LogCat. Should I be doing this in a different class and if so how, or is it just something I have to fix in my current code.

```
public class PasteCode extends Activity {

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pastecode);

    final EditText codeinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    Button send_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    send_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String code = codeinput.getText().toString();

            new Thread( new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("accounts.google.com");

                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", code));
                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "----------------------"));
                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", "-----------------"));
                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"));
                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"));

                    try {
                        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));

                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        // writing error to Log
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Making HTTP Request
                    try {
                        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                        // writing response to log
                        Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // writing exception to log
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // writing exception to log
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
}
}
```

LogView

02-18   10:03:20.477: W/dalvikvm(3759):         threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught
                        exception (group=0x4001d760)

02-18 10:03:20.487: E/AndroidRuntime(3759):     FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-31

02-18 10:03:20.487: E/AndroidRuntime(3759):     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target 
                        host must not be null, or set in parameters. 
                        scheme=null, host=null, 
                        path=accounts.google.com

02-18 10:03:20.487: E/AndroidRuntime(3759):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)

Answer (score -1):

Good morning could you please post the logcat error please... actually android does not allow you to make a http request in the main thread of the app... there are some ways to achieve what you are looking for... first you can implement you thread as an asyncTask... or just for developing purposes you can remove the polycies you can add these lines to your code in the onCreate of your activity...

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

but this is not recomended...

EDIT:

ok I see your error there is no database or nothing to handle the data you are sending... could you please post the code you have on the server side... and also check the url you are sending data... it seems not to be valid... I will post one example to show you how to get this to work..!!

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data1", "data"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data2", "dataa"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data3", "dataaa"));
        try {
            res = CustomHttpClient.sendData("URL", nameValuePairs);
            String resp = res.toString();
            Log.e(Tag, res);
            resp = resp.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

as you can see I am making an instance of custom http client wich the one in charge to make the call to the server... and is also in charge of handle the answer from the server...

public class CustomHttpClient{

```
public static final int HTTP_TIMEOT = 30 * 1000;
private static HttpClient mHttpClient;

private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
    if (mHttpClient == null) ;
    {
        mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpParams param = mHttpClient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(param, HTTP_TIMEOT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(param, HTTP_TIMEOT);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(param, HTTP_TIMEOT);
    }
    return mHttpClient;
}

public static String sendData(String url, ArrayList nameValuePairs) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = getHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
        httppost.setEntity(formEntity);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sBuffer.append(line + NL);
        }
        reader.close();
        String result = sBuffer.toString();
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I solved that error by just adding "http://" to the path name, now I am struggling to read the response that I got.

Comment: The response is supposed to contain the access token of the user I am authenticating. I did this in my code -                          Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());                           and in LogCat it shows                                                 Http Response  -  org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@43454f20 so how do I read the message

Comment: you can try with this tutorial... http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app